# OpenWhisk rule still triggers when disabled

Tags: ibm-cloud, openwhisk

I have a trigger and a rule that fire regularly using cron.

In the develop UI I disabled the rule, but it all appears to still be firing and hitting my action...

Answer (score 0):

You can install the [OpenWhisk CLI](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/openwhisk/learn/cli) and check the status of your rule there.

If the rule appears to be disabled there as well, we have a bug in the system itself. It'd be great if you could open an issue then here: https://github.com/openwhisk/openwhisk/issues.

As for the UI, you can request help via the **Support** tab in the top-right corner.